# Code::Blocks program doesn't run properly when run button is hit

Tags: c++, codeblocks, windows-security

I have been compiling and running programs in C++ on Code::Blocks longly but today one of my programs compiled successfully but when I ran the program it returned -12 with time -0.00s. Whenever I write a new program in C++ the program compiles but it doesn't run. Also when I open the executable file created by Code::Blocks in the same directory Windows takes permission from me to allow the executable file to make changes to the computer. I've been trying through the day but I couldn't figure out what could be going wrong.

Also when I tried uninstalling Code::Blocks it didn't uninstall completely and when I opened the Code::Blocks folder in Program Files and tried deleting the folder the folder MinGW couldn't be deleted because Access was denied.

Please help if you could comprehend the problem and have knowledge regarding the issue.

Comment: Are you using avast antivirus?

Comment: No I'm using Net protector antivirus.

Comment: Shut it down briefly, just to see....

Comment: Try disabling it anyway and see if this solves the problem.

Comment: Could there be an issue with windows?

Comment: Tried running the program after disabling but it made no difference.